# Output javascript date month as text? Using C3.js

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, d3.js, c3.js

The demo below outputs the month part of the date string as numeric **months** 1-12 and applies it to the **x axis** values.

- How can the months be output as text: **Jan, Feb, Mar...** ? *(Even if this is hardcoded as text, I cannot find a type format of text,string).*

The documentation for c3 is currently limited and my trials so far have been unsuccessful.

```js
    var chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#chart',
      data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: [
            ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-02-01', '2013-03-01', '2013-04-01', '2013-05-01', '2013-06-01', '2013-07-01', '2013-08-01', '2013-09-01', '2013-10-01', '2013-11-01', '2013-12-01'],
            ['2014', 130, 120, 150, 140, 160, 150, 130, 120, 150, 140, 160, 150]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
      },
      axis: {
        x: {
          type: 'timeseries',
          tick: {
            format: function (x) { return (x.getMonth() + 1); }
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://gopeter.de/misc/c3/c3.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason you need timeseries? Category might be better.

**TO USE C3 CATEGORIES FOR AXIS TYPE**

This method is good if your x axis needs to be numerical. Useful for regions, axis range or individual gridlines (I'm sure there are others). You can not assign a region to category data.

```
var chart2 = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      x: 'x',
      columns: [
        ['x', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 50, 100, 250]
      ],
      type: 'bar'
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
        categories: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine'],
        type: 'categorized'
      }
    },
    regions: [
        {axis: 'x', start: 1, end: 5, class: 'regionX'},
    ]
  });
```

http://c3js.org/samples/categorized.html

This method below is simpler. This is effective when the hardest thing you need to do is dynamically update the x axis with a chart.load function.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  data: {
    x: 'x',
    columns: [
      ['x', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
      ['2014', 130, 120, 150, 140, 160, 150, 130, 120, 150, 140, 160, 150]
    ],
    type: 'bar'
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'categorized',
    }
  }
});
```

http://c3js.org/samples/data_stringx.html

Comment: This is great. Yes definately what I was looking for. I couldn't find a list of the "types" in the examples, any chance you can point me a list of possible axis types?

Comment: Found it thanks. I believe your syntax was wrong though. I've added an edit to your post, that worked for me.

Comment: I just tried your code, that doesn't work for me. The way I had it works for me, and is documented. Here it is - http://c3js.org/samples/data_stringx.html.
I think the way I had it was fine, and works.

Comment: How strange. Appreciate the help anyway, it was exactly what I needed. Maybe you should add both examples to your answer.

Comment: Yep, just did that. Cheers!

Comment: Adding x to the columns data (your way) allows for the axis information to be updated dynamically.

Comment: Righto, had no idea. Thanks mate.

Comment: Obsidian I figured it out. Your method allows for charts with regions. Regions will not work on the x axis if categories are declared in the column. Declare x as numbers to set regions for x axis

Answer (score 3):

**try this:**

```
format: function (x) { return (x.getMonth() + 1); }
```

this section change to

```
 format: function(x) {
              var month = ["jan", "feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"];

              return (month[x.getMonth()]);
            }
```

**full code here:**

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  data: {
    x: 'x',
    columns: [
      ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-02-01', '2013-03-01', '2013-04-01', '2013-05-01', '2013-06-01', '2013-07-01', '2013-08-01', '2013-09-01', '2013-10-01', '2013-11-01', '2013-12-01'],
      ['2014', 130, 120, 150, 140, 160, 150, 130, 120, 150, 140, 160, 150]
    ],
    type: 'bar'
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'timeseries',
      tick: {
        format: function(x) {
          var month = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];

          return (month[x.getMonth()]);
        },
        fit: false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://gopeter.de/misc/c3/c3.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the name of the month using the `date` object in [javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp). I have included a simple arrray to do the mapping.

Also, the printing of alternative values might have to do something with the `fit` option of the [tick](http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-fit) which by default is `true`.

The following code snippet should work.

```js
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
var chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#chart',
      data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: [
            ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-02-01', '2013-03-01', '2013-04-01', '2013-05-01', '2013-06-01', '2013-07-01', '2013-08-01', '2013-09-01', '2013-10-01', '2013-11-01', '2013-12-01'],
            ['2014', 130, 120, 150, 140, 160, 150, 130, 120, 150, 140, 160, 150]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
      },
      axis: {
        x: {
          type: 'timeseries',
          tick: {
            format: function (x) { return (monthNames[x.getMonth()]); },
            fit: false
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://gopeter.de/misc/c3/c3.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```